# Python Engines to Beat to Take the Crown

Tags: engines, python

Since Python is extremely slow, chess engines are almost never written using it.  I've been building a Python engine to avoid this issue (through JIT compilation), and want to compare my engine against other 'pure Python' engines.

I'm defining a 'pure Python' engine as an engine where all the core functionality is written in Python.  An example of this would be an engine which is written in all Python except for a tiny bit of C used to efficiently stitch together the use of a few Python packages.

Given that definition, I'm wondering which engine's would need to be beaten in order to fairly say my engine is the "Best Python Engine" running on [my computer hardware](https://pcpartpicker.com/user/da_sammy/saved/j7KGGX).

If you'd like to test against my engine, or are just curious about it, my chess engine is [Batch-First](https://github.com/SamRagusa/Batch-First) (although as of writing this the trained ANNs aren't currently uploaded).

Answer (score 2):

You may claim yourself the World Computer Champion in Python if you beat all of them:

> http://talkchess.com/forum3/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=67025